# JS script for filtering div section doesnt work with carousel bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, filter, carousel

it's been a while i'm working on it but yet i'm so far from a solution.
Right now i've got a huge pages with tons of DIV that must be hiden till someone select it.
Normally it works fine but when i've to show a div where inside there's a carousel, the carousel will start showing all the images instead of showing one per time.

Sry for my poor english, thanks in advance

*************UPDATE***************

Well i've found the iusse but still not the solution. The Iusse is about the carousel that doesnt work if it's on a hidden div during the loading page. is there any way to make it starts when his div became visible from being hide? Using carousel bootstrap, thanks in advance

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  var value = this.value,
    all = $('.item'),
    selected = all.filter('.' + "none");

  all.hide();
  selected.show();
  $('#item-filter-select').change(function() {

    var value = this.value,
      all = $('.item'),
      selected = all.filter('.' + value);

    all.hide();
    selected.show();

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item-filter portfolio-filter cbp-l-filters-button text-center">
  <form>
    <select id="item-filter-select">
      <option value="none" id="none">select</option>
      <option value="test" id="test">testPlan</option>
      <option value="try" id="try">Try</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="item-display" id="item-display">
  <div class="item test" id="item-test" data-type="test">
    <div class="cbp-item test">
      <div class="container text-center pt150 pb140">
        <div class="service-desc pb60 bg-white">
          <h3>H3 TEST</h3>
          <h4></h4>
        </div>
        <br>
        <p>
          some text
        </p>
        <div class="row bg-gray pt40 pb40">
          <div class="col-lg-1">

          </div>
          <!-- team member -->
          <div class="col-lg-5 wow fadeInDown" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-wow-delay="200ms">
            <article class="team-mate">
              <div class="member-photo">
                <!-- features media -->
                <div id="myCarousel20" class="carousel slide col-lg-12 feature-media wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="500ms" data-ride="carousel">
                  <!-- Indicators -->
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel20" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel20" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel20" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel20" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                  </ol>
                  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item test active">
                      <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pretty-office-10/24/Test-paper-24.png" class="img-center" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item test ">
                      <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-icon/test-quiz_318-86103.jpg" class="img-center" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item test">
                      <img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/pretty-office-10/24/Test-paper-24.png" class="img-center" alt="">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- member name & designation -->
              <div class="member-title">
                <h3>test</h3>
                <span></span>
              </div>
              <!-- /member name & designation -->

              <!-- about member -->
              <div class="member-info">
                <p>

                </p>
              </div>
              <!-- /about member -->
            </article>
          </div>
          <!-- end team member -->
          <div class="col-lg-1">

          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- End row -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on exactly what you are trying to do with your javascript?

Comment: I need a little more info to help. What is the condition you are trying to filter through.?

Comment: Yes, sry. What i'm trying to do is to havea  filtering option ( the select "button") that helps me to show div that usually are hide when u first load the page. Usually the script im using it's working fine when the div that i've to show it's composed by "text, img, text". The problem starts when the div has " text, carousel images, text" because the carousel will not works properly infect it will show all the images togheter instead of showing one bye one.

Comment: P.S if u Scroll down the page (http://www.marcodavi.it/prova/vendita-immobili-pragelato.php) and go to the select option and u select "THIS" u will see what i'm saying :)

Comment: On your above code example you have a class of `item`; I believe it should be `carousel-item`. If I'm looking at it correctly, on your website your carousel is not formatted properly. A couple images will pop up but when I inspect the source, in your html, you have the `carousel` class on each div surrounding a single image and the a single `item` inside of that. Again it should be `carousel-item`

Comment: Not sure if I was clear on my last comment but the `carousel` class should be the parent of the all the included pictures and those should have the `carousel-item` class.

Comment: yeah most of my div have a carousel with only 1 image just because after i saw how was working wrong the carousel i , for the moment, removed the other images just for seeing if the style of the page was ok.
back to the script i'm not sure if i understood right, are u saying i should put carousel-item instead of item? can u give me an example? Thanks you so much

Comment: I'm saying the class for the carousel item needs to be `carousel-item` not `item`

Comment: I added an answer with a working example of a bootstrap carousel. Try to set yours up like that. I think the main problem you're having is the incorrect class name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in the end i've found a solution though.
I've changed a bit the script into this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.
    var value = this.value,
        all = $('.item'),
        selected = all.filter('.' + "none");

    all.hide();
    selected.show();
    $('#item-filter-select').change(function() {

        var value = this.value,
            all = $('.item'),
            selected = all.filter('.' + value);
            if(value=='test'){
              all.hide();
            $('#item-test').load(document.URL +  ' #item-test');
            selected.show();
          }else{
        all.hide();
        selected.show();
      }


    });

});
```

Now everytime i select the hidden div having a carousel inside it will first load the div again [ $('#item-test').load(document.URL +  ' #item-test'); ] and then it will show it up [ selected.show(); ].

I Hope it will be usefull for others to.